# Amazon MWS Buyer Messages

Tags: amazon-mws

I am trying to develop an app for my amazon account using MWS. I need to fetch order details and send messages to my buyers. But I am unable to find the API function for that in MWS developer Guide.

Answer (score 0):

While the way to fetch order details is probably clear (part of the MWS API), there is no API for customer messages. However, you can use a regular email client to receive and answer those messages. If you wish to use an API to integrate it in your solution, you'll need to use an otherwise unused email account and POP/IMAP and SMTP, just like an email client would.

Answer (score 0):

I used two Report APIs to get orders's details and its buyers's info, for me it works well:

1. The first one is _GET_FLAT_FILE_ALL_ORDERS_DATA_BY_LAST_UPDATE_, it can provides me all the orders's details by passing to it the start date and end date of the orders's last update time, it won't tell you the buyers's info.
2. The second one is _GET_AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENTS_DATA_, it show me the buyers's basic info, include email address where you can send messages to.

**You can get more details about the above APIs by reading the [MWS Documentation](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__OrderReports), and try to call it for the report.**